# Loading data from a shapefile

Tags: geography

After saving (with QGis) the part of the map I´m interested in for a local visualization, I have the .zip file where you can see 5 files. 
I load the map in Mathematica with

```
e1 = Import["Estrada.zip"]
```

all works fine.

But the problem is... when I want to list the name of every region, I can´t find the names, but I can see LayerNames if I type

```
e2 = Import["Estrada.zip","Elements"]
```

zip file at https://we.tl/t-NqBdMYcOSN
(sorry for not attanching to the message, if I must upload the file to another site, please tell me)

I´m doing bad anything or is not available the LayerName in this zip file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does appear that `"LayerNames"` does not work correctly with Shapefile zips - I would recommend emailing WRI support about this, as I think it's a bug.

As a workaround, you can unzip the shapefile zip and import the `.shp` inside instead of importing the zip file.

I uncompressed the zip file locally (just by double-clicking the zip file), and then I can do:

```
Import["~/Downloads/Estrada/estrada.shp", {"SHP", "LayerNames"}]
```

> `"estrada"`

Which (I checked) is the only layer in the file.

You can get the Graphics object like so:

```
Import["~/Downloads/Estrada/estrada.shp", {"SHP", "Graphics"}]
```

> [image]

and the data like so:

```
Import["~/Downloads/Estrada/estrada.shp", {"SHP", "Data"}]
```

For example, you can get the names of each area by doing:

```
Association[
  Association[
    Import["~/Downloads/Estrada/estrada.shp", {"SHP", "Data"}]][
   "LabeledData"]]["PARROQUIA"]
```

> [image]

By the way, `"LayerNames"` may not be what you think they are. They are the names of *layers* in the shapefile, rather than objects *within* a layer. The file you have only shows a single layer. In QGIS, you can see this in the bottom left:

> [image]

One thing to note: your data purports to be, but is not, in the EPSG:4326 spatial reference system. I would recommend exporting in this SRS if you wish to use the geospatial data within Mathematica.

I have determined that your data is in the UTM Zone 29 SRS (EPSG:32629). You can set this as such in QGIS and export as 4326, or you can happily use these positions in Mathematica, now that we know what they are.

To use this in Mathematica, we need `GeoGridPosition`.

Let's convert the geometry in the `Data` field to `GeoGridPosition`:

```
geom = Association[
   Import["~/Downloads/Estrada/estrada.shp", {"SHP", "Data"}]][
  "Geometry"] /. 
  Polygon[x_] :> (Polygon[GeoGridPosition[#, "UTMZone29"] & /@ x])
```

Now we can use it like any normal `GeoPosition`:

[image]

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[AssociationThread[
  geom,
  Association[
    Association[
      Import["~/Downloads/Estrada/estrada.shp", {"SHP", "Data"}]][
     "LabeledData"]]["SUPERFICIE"]]]
```

[image]

Finally, though this is a Mathematica forum, here is how to generate similar plots in QGIS, since you mentioned it:

[image]

giving

[image]

[You asked the right person ;)](https://toughsoles.ie/maps)

Comment: Yes I unzipped files but I can´t load the names. Thank you for the advices, i´m trying

Comment: @MikaIke See my edit. By the way, "LayerNames" may not be what you think they are. They are the names of layers in the shapefile, rather than objects within a layer. The file you have only has a single layer.

Comment: I have no the SRS option. I must revise what you explain, and leearn more about shp. https://i.postimg.cc/wxFh5vFy/snapw01145.jpg

Comment: @MikaIke, What country is this data for? That will help to narrow down what the SRS should be.

Comment: for the northwest of Spain (South of Europe), at the north of Portugal.

Comment: @MikaIke Your data is in the SRS UTMZone29 - you can figure it out using this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#UTM_zone. Edit incoming to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92510/discussion-between-mika-ike-and-carl-lange).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92540/discussion-between-mika-ike-and-carl-lange).